# Graal Native image: Resource not found: "io/trino/jdbc/$internal/joda/time/tz/data/ZoneInfoMap" ClassLoader

Tags: jodatime, graalvm-native-image

I am packing an application which connects with trino server in graal native image. When I ran the built docker image, I got this error:

> java.io.IOException: Resource not found: "io/trino/jdbc/$internal/joda/time/tz/data/ZoneInfoMap" ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4b6995df

I have tried to include ZoneInfoMap resource into native-image.properties file, after building the docker image again, it asked for GMT again:

> java.io.IOException: Resource not found: "io/trino/jdbc/$internal/joda/time/tz/data/Etc/GMT" ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4b6995df

I am not sure if including each resource is the correct way to solve this issue. Has anyone had any experience or suggestions?

Comment: Hi Yudan, did you mange to find a solution? Experiencing the same issue with Joda Time brought into the project as AWS SDK dependency.